# SEO - redirect old urls to node/### paths or node aliases?

Tags: redirection

We've got an old site that we just finished migrating to D8. We are adding a ton of redirects to the site, but I'm wondering whether it's best to issue these redirects to the new node/### paths or their path aliases?

My gut tells me to issue the redirects to the node/### paths since those will always and forever stay the same, whereas something might happen to the path aliases. I know that redirect handles auto-redirecting old aliases to new aliases, but in the event that something goes wrong with this I figure it's better to have the redirects pointing to the node/### paths instead.

Any thoughts?

Comment: We also use `node/###` for exactly the same reasons you've written, and so far it has worked for us, also in multilingual enviroments

Comment: I hadn't even thought about  multilingual, but that's a great point. That will be a concern for us eventually so definitely something to consider